# If Statement With Is Keyword And Comparison To Null

Tags: c#, .net, null, typechecking

I installed Reshaper today on my PC to check it out and whenever I have following statement in my code I get an info from Resharper that comparing to `Null` is not necessary. Why?

This is the statement:

```
if (dataGrid.ItemsSource != null && dataGrid.ItemsSource is DataGridCollectionView)
```

I am checking if the type is the one I want it to be and if the value is not `Null`.

It makes sense for me to ask for this because the type might be true though the value might be still `Null`. I guess I must be missing something in documentation about this.

Why does Reshaper say I dont need to compare to null?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `is` operator will always return `false` if the object is null, so you do not need to check for null before testing the type.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is *non-null*, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

`dataGrid.ItemsSource is DataGridCollectionView` means "dataGrid.ItemsSource is an instance of `DataGridCollectionView`"; if it's an instance (of anything), it can't be null, so the null check is redundant.

Comment: Does IS keyword always returns false when null? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, [is (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.90).aspx): *An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is **non-null**, and....*

Comment: Yes, it always returns false when the value is null, because null isn't an instance of any type. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx: *An is expression evaluates to true **if the provided expression is non-null**, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.*

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate your help. I guess I missed that line.

Answer (score 2):

`null` will always return `false` from an `is` test, so the `null` check doesn't achieve anything that the `is` test doesn't already do. The only **insane edge case** where this could misbehave is if you had a property that returned different things on successive invocations - so if the first `.ItemsSource` returned something very different to the second `.ItemsSource`. Which would be dangerous and self-inflicted.

Comment: Really? Is this documented somewhere on MSDN?

Comment: @devhedgehog IIRC, the language specification; section 7.9.10 in the MS version

Comment: @devhedgehog here's the ECMA version, http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/14.9.9.htm : "If the value of e is null, the result is false."